# Can I pass an additional attachment to DocuSign to include in the email notification?

Tags: docusignapi

I have an agreement summary page that I want to pass to specific signers (only internal signers) that I would like to include as an attachment to the email notification to the signer.  The document does not require any DocuSign processing.  I can pass a href link in the message, but it contains username:password which renders it unsecure.

Comment: No, however you could use Document Visibility to make that Document part of the envelope for specific people, and leave it out for other specific people.

Comment: DocuSign never sends documents through email (that's not secure and defeats the whole purpose) but as Andrew has mentioned document visibility feature might work for you.  Check out the answer I just posted...

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew has stated you can use the **Document Visibility** feature to control which recipients can see which document(s).  This can be configured on a given envelope through the DocuSign Web Console as well as through the API.

To test things out follow this guide for setting document visibility in a template in your account:

https://www.docusign.com/support/classic/documentation/cdse-user-guide/advanced-sending/using-document-visibility-in-a-template

Also check out this previously answered SO post which has some more insight into how it works:

[Limit visibility on documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989973/limit-visibility-on-documents)